# Is it haram to change the wife's last name to that of the husband's?

Tags: nikah, wife, naming

I got married recently and my husband wants me to change my surname to his name.

First of all, I read it somewhere that in Islam it is not allowed for a wife to use her husband's name as her surname. This was a little surprising for me. So, before I do something I want to know if this is right or wrong?

There is one more thing and that is, I am a little afraid to change my name as names have a lot of effects on one's life. I don't know which option to choose. I wanted to ask a scholar before changing my name.

Answer (score 2):

According to this source:  http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/articles/157172/wife-taking-her-husbands-surname

No.

"Naming the wife after the name of her husband and neglecting the name of her father is not permissible."

Comment: " neglecting the name of her father is " - doesn't mean surname in itself, it just means that you shouldnt change the womans name from bint ahmed to bint karim for instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing in Qur'an or hadith that says that a wife cannot adopt her husband's surname. The quotations linked by s91 did not say anything about this specific matter. I agree with Farhan: this is matter of culture and not of religion.

Answer (score 0):

It is common in some countries where wife take husbands name as surname. Some people use this name only unofficially but there are some who change it officially, like even in Passport. But this is only a cultural thing and according to Islam there is no basis for this name changing. The reason is a woman's husband can change either due to husband's death or divorce. So woman may need to change her documents when this happens. But if she is called after her father, this is permanent. In Quran also, we can see asking to call upon father's name 
"Call them by [the names of] their fathers; it is more just in the sight of Allah . " Quran 33:5 http://quran.com/33/5

Answer (score -1):

Call them (adopted sons) by (the names of) their fathers, that is more just with Allaah [al-Ahzaab 33:5]

Comment: Would it be possible to build on this answer please?  In particular, I suggest tying it in with the question *Is it haram to change the wife's last name to that of the husband's?* (perhaps using tafseer to support any deductions).

Answer (score -2):

The prophet saw said it is practice of kufar to change your surname and you associated yourself to your husband like a relative and there is a place in hell were you associate yourself with other than your father

Comment: Do you know in which hadith?